# How to return IQueryable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There is container

```
_userTable = new UserTable<TUser>(_database);
```

I need a function returns collection from this container. How to return this type of collection here?

```cs
    public IQueryable<TUser> Users
    {
        get { return _userTable; }// <----------?
    }
```

There is

```cs
public class UserTable<TUser>
    where TUser : IdentityUser
```

```
I need the users list to display it in razor page
 public void GetUsers()
    {
        ColUsers = new List<PUser>();
        var user = _UserManager.Users.Select(x => new PUser
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            UserName = x.UserName,
            Email = x.Email,
            PasswordHash = "*****"
        });

        foreach (var item in user)
        {
            ColUsers.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `UserTable`?

Comment: can you clarify: what is `UserTable<T>` here? is it your own thing? is it some library (Microsoft or otherwise)? Without knowing more about it, it is hard to say whether it even *makes sense* to consider this, let alone whether it will do what you expect (which: you also don't define)

Comment: Sorry, it is ASP.NET Core Identity provider

Comment: @Oleg by that, do you mean that it is your own thing where you're trying to implement `IQueryableUserStore<TUser>` ? That still doesn't tell me much about what `UserTable<TUser>` is. It ... kinda matters. There's a huge difference between an *actual* queryable store, vs `IEnumerable<T>` exposing a queryable API via `AsQueryable()`

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, right. Iit is my custom Identity provider. I make an implementation without EF and working with PostgreSQL

Comment: @Oleg the problem is: `IQueryable<T>` is a very specific API; if you don't *have* a query provider, frankly IMO you should just implement `IUserStore<T>`, not `IQueryableUserStore<T>`; I'm guessing you don't want to constantly load all your users into memory, and I'm guessing you don't want to write a query provider (which is a **massive** amount of work requiring detailed knowledge of express trees and query generators)

Comment: For an intro-level guide on writing a query provider, I recommend Chapter 12 of Jon Skeet's C# in Depth

Comment: @canton7 I recall C# in Depth covering LINQ in the `IEnumerable<T>` sense; I don't remember it going into details on query providers, other than conceptually - has that changed?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've got the 2nd edition, and that has an intro using a "fake query provider" in section 12.2. It doesn't go into much depth (and doesn't contain enough info to write e.g. a linq-to-sql translation layer), but it's an intro.

Comment: @MarcGravell ok. The one reason is: I need the users list for using it in razor page in function (see above in the 1st message)

Comment: @Oleg. The message to you is, this is a very complicated thing, like writing your own printer driver. Normal people just use classes implementing IQueryable, they never implement it themselves anywhere. On the other hand most functions offered for IQuerable are offered for IEnumerable also (LINQ to objects). This is way more easy to implement an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, you've got limited options here;

1. get hold of a full query provider - something like EF - and use that:

   ```
   public IQueryable<TUSer> Users => _myDbContext.Users;
   ```
2. load all the users into something like a `List<T>`, and use `AsQueryable()` - this will *spoof* the query API using LINQ-to-Objects, and will force it to load all the users into memory, but is simple:

   ```
   public IQueryable<TUser> Users => LoadThemAll().AsQueryable();
   ```
3. roll your own query provider that knows how to convert expression trees into executable queries for your RDBMS; this is a *huge* amount of work, where just the overview and explanations (not the work itself) would fill a modest sized book

Order of usual preference is order listed. Alternatively, limit yourself to `IUserStore<T>` (not `IQueryableUserStore<T>`), and get the list of users in some other manner.

Comment: yes, I see. I am trying to restore one of existing custom providers. Its author has stopped working on it but some of interfaces were not implemented. There is the file and at the end of it the function https://github.com/Robynhu/AspNetCore.Identity.PostgreSQL/blob/master/AspNetCore.Identity.PostgreSQL/Stores/UserStore.cs

Comment: Thank you Marc, I implemented it this way: Added the reading from db list of users and then converted to IQueryable. The list will be not so large.